# HAProxy MySQL Failover is not starting

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, haproxy, high-availability

I am trying to setup HAProxy with MySQL failover with Ubuntu. I used a setup similar to [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/352253/haproxy-mysql-failover-load-balancing), however I am getting the following error when starting haproxy:

```
[ALERT] 341/220001 (17405) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:29] : unknown option 'mysql-check'.
[ALERT] 341/220001 (17405) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 341/220001 (17405) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

I even tried installing the lastest version of HAProxy (1.4.22). Does anyone know how to fix this? I have Google'd the heck out of it and can't find any solution.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you please paste here your /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it was available. I was just running the wrong version. Before I complied HAProxy I installed it from the repo which was at version 1.3. I stopped that versions daemon and started the 1.4 version and everything works! NOOB mistake.