# Mariadb active passive failover doesn't work with HAProxy

Tags: mysql, haproxy, mariadb, galera, load-balance

What is wrong with my HAProxy config?

This thread kind of similar, but still not the same: [Haproxy mysql failover load balancing](https://serverfault.com/questions/352253/haproxy-mysql-failover-load-balancing)

I have an active-passive Mariadb galera cluster.
Today on the master node the MYSQL process stopped due to winbind oomkill.
The failover to the slave node didn't happen, because with my current setup seems like only works if the node down, but if MYSQL process down doesn't do anything :/

This is my HAProxy config:

```
defaults
    retries                 2
    timeout connect         5s
    timeout client          60s
    timeout server          60s

listen Mariadb-cluster
bind 0.0.0.0:3306
mode tcp
option mysql-check user haproxy
balance roundrobin
server server1-DB1 1.1.1.1:13306 check
server server2-2002-DB2 1.1.1.2:13306 check backup

listen webinterface
bind 0.0.0.0:9000 ssl crt /com.pem
mode http
balance
timeout client 5000
timeout connect 4000
timeout server 30000
stats enable
stats uri /
stats realm Strictly\ Private
stats auth admin:sdfsdf
```

This is the keepalived:

```
global_defs {
        lvs_id LBL
}

vrrp_sync_group CLD  {
        group {
                CLOUD
        }
}

vrrp_script check_haproxy {
        script "killall -0 haproxy"
        interval 2
        weight 2
}

vrrp_instance CLOUD {
  virtual_router_id 13
  priority  100
  state     BACKUP
  interface eth0

  virtual_ipaddress {
        1.1.1.3/24 dev eth0
  }

  track_script {
    check_haproxy
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check for the state of the mysqld instead of haproxy?

Comment: The haproxy seems to be pretty useless in this constellation anyway.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You mean in keepalive?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution but this did the job for now, adding weight and check port.

```
server server1-DB1 1.1.1.1:13306 weight 1 check port 13306
server server2-2002-DB2 1.1.1.2:13306 weight 100 check port 13360 backup
```